# How can I route a trap when the drain inlet is too close to my disposal unit?

Tags: plumbing, garbage-disposal, kitchen-sink

I am installing a trap into my new sink. I've installed the garbage disposal, and also the new strainer. The problem I have come across is the fact the trap is WAY too close to the garbage disposal outlet. I'm not sure if I can re-route without disturbing the water drainage flow.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Ryan, please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand what's expected of you with your question. Thanks.

Comment: I have everything set up. Everything is glued. I tested the water, and its draining all fine, until it its the P-Trap union......literally leaking from the union....am I screwed, or should putty work? Right now it has a small drip until the water suffices.

Comment: Putty has no place in modern plumbing. Without knowing how you have thing assembled, we can't really help. A I tried to indicate, we're not a discussion forum. If you have a new question, please post it as such.

Answer (score 2):

This is really difficult to explain. For starters, you can't use the tail piece attached to the left basin. It's wrong. I've put an image together, but it's ugly. It still may help tho.
[image: Demo picture]

[image: Heres one I found online with 3 different scenarios]

Comment: Thank you! The diagram shows the GD on the left side. I would like to keep it on the right due to the power plug, and the switch being there. I like the idea, and thats what I was thinking previously. If I add the trap to the left and route to the stub, will it effect the drain? Meaning the p-trap wont be directly into the stub, looks like I will need to reroute a 45'

Comment: You may get slightly more noise and backsplash with this arrangement, but it's how mine is set up, too, with my dishwasher routing through the disposal unit as well.

Comment: Bill, you didn't explain how the tailpiece is wrong. Do you mean because it drops too low? Please revise to clarify.

Comment: Technically, the tailpiece there can be used, but using it means it needs to be cut and then a T adapter installed, which creates a joint that can possibly leak, along with then wasting about 6" of the tailpiece. A tailpiece with an integrated T is a much better approach.

Comment: @Ryan The photos were just for reference. You can still put your GD where you like.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just put the garbage disposal on the other sink basin?

If not then cut the waste pipe coming out of the wall a little shorter and  put a 45° elbow  on it and a stub out piece on that to accept the  pipe from the P-trap at an angle.  The P-trap will allow you to swing out its feed to match the 45° angle of the waste pipe from the wall.

Either way, as Bill pointed out you’ll need a tail piece with a T connection on it.

Comment: I think if I want to keep the GD in this location, I will have to do that. I was just afraid that the water flow would be off if the trap isnt directly into the wall stub. Thank you!