# Sink Drainage Configuration

Tags: plumbing, drain, garbage-disposal

I have a double sink, garbage Disposal & dishwasher. There must be a better way. How I can modify this to make it better?

[image]

Comment: That seems to be extended as far as possible for ease of access to the drain on the disposal, that setup can be cut down by almost half if you turn the disposal left 45 degrees

Comment: You could also use an extendable drain such as this https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B00I2XQ56U?psc=1&ref=yo_pop_mb_pd_title

Comment: What are you trying to improve about this setup?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not leaking, don't fix it. But if it bothers you that much...

For starters, typically on a dual sink setup such as this, the garbage disposal drain is pointing towards the other sink basin. For the sink basin without the garbage disposal, there is a tailpiece, which is also a T, attached to the drain. Come straight out of the garbage disposal to the T in the tailpiece for the opposing basin. At the bottom of the tailpiece is where your trap goes, then to the drain line stubbed out of the wall.

I answered a question similar to this a few days ago with some diagrams. Let me find a link to it and I'll update my answer with it.

Edit:
Here's the [link](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/148441/91866) to a similar question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments but I'm not very clear on what you're proposing. Can you provide a sketch? -How easy is it to position the garbage disposal to face the other sink? -Can I extend a pipe directly from the disposal to the other sink drain & then have it go to the p trap? -The hose from the dishwasher to the disposal hangs low, is that a problem?
Thanks again.

Comment: Did you follow the link at the bottom of my post? It takes you to a similar question I had previously answered, with diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Bill explained it,  here is [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Ut3vO1Y0SA) video that shows it.

You may be able to rotate your disposal by hand without loosening it but you may have to loosen the ring that holds the unit to the sink just a little to get it to move. search YouTube for disposal installation and you will get all the info you need.

*For future reference you should not put questions or comments in the answer feild like you did for bill's answer, use the comment link under the answer to ask for clarification to the answer*.

Comment: thanks for pointing out how to follow up. It seems that the dishwasher drainage hose that feeds into the garbage disposal is hanging in such a way that it causes back flow into the dishwasher. Any suggestions on how to line that up?